# Add third color level to Javascript/JQuery HTML Table Heatmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, math, heatmap

I'm using a HTML table heatmap JQuery script by:

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tutorial-create-a-flexible-data-heat-map/

I've been able to modify it and get it cleaned up and working with our data sets. However, the current script only allows for two colors and does not calculate the medium with a standard deviation to include a third color such as yellow.

Here is the current script below:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Function to get the Max value in Array
        Array.max = function (array) {
            return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
        };

        // get all values
        var counts = $('.heatmap tbody td').not('.first_row').map(function () {
            return parseInt($(this).text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, ""));
        }).get();

        // return max value
        var max = Array.max(counts);

        // red color for lowest data
        xr = 251;
        xg = 121;
        xb = 105;

        // green color for highest data
        yr = 138;
        yg = 251;
        yb = 107;
        n = 100;

        // add classes to cells based on nearest 10 value
        $('.heatmap tbody td').not('.first_row').each(function () {
            var val = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, ""));
            var pos = parseInt((Math.round((val / max) * 100)).toFixed(0));
            red = parseInt((xr + ((pos * (yr - xr)) / (n - 1))).toFixed(0));
            green = parseInt((xg + ((pos * (yg - xg)) / (n - 1))).toFixed(0));
            blue = parseInt((xb + ((pos * (yb - xb)) / (n - 1))).toFixed(0));
            clr = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
            $(this).css({
                backgroundColor: clr
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The heatmap currently goes from red to green and I want to add a calculation that adds yellow for the medium range. I've created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7z8D4/ with the script and heatmap table structure I'm using.

For Example, if I have the following data sets, it should be colored such as:

```
1      red
2      red
3      pink
4      pink
5      yellow
6      yellow
7      lime green
8      lime green
9      green
10     green
```

I really appreciate any insights on this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

red (at 0%) to yellow (at 50%) to green (at 100%)

```
var pos = val / (max * 1.0);

red =  Math.round(pos < 0.5 ? 255 : ((1 - pos) * 2) * 255);
green = Math.round(pos < 0.5 ? (pos * 2) * 255 : 255);
blue = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a pretty simple JavaScript function (see http://jsfiddle.net/4vCfc/) that provides an RGB color on a Red through yellow and then blue color gradient that I'm using for a heatmap to demonstrate usage of fields in a form.

Here's the function definition:

```
function getHeatColorAsRbg(percentage) //percent is a number between 0 and 1.
{
//RED - YELLOW (255, 0, 0) to (255, 255, 0)
//THEN YELLOW TO BLUE (255,255,0) to (0, 0, 255)
var red = 0;
var blue = 0;
var green = 0;

//Two cases - 1.0 down to 0.5 and 0.5 down to 0.

if(percentage >= 0.5)
{
    red = 255;
    green = Math.round(255 * 2 * (1 - percentage));
    blue = 0;
}
else
{
    blue = 255 - Math.round((percentage/0.5)*255);
    red = 255 - blue;
    green = red;
}

return "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Without finding the Minimum in array your methods are just half-methods.))

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: my dear, if you will give always ready/final answers, you will not always help.